How can I use eslint:recommended and Google in eslint 9 with commonjs syntax?
I have a new project I want to use Eslint9 for. I want a clean setup and therefore utilize the new format.
As the project is a WebApp, it's a script/common.js and not a module syntax.
I tried to set up Eslint9 for this and got this pretty basic eslint.config.js file
module.exports = [
  {
    files: ["**/*.js"],
    ignores:  ["**/*.min.js"],
    languageOptions: {
      sourceType: "script", 
    },
    rules: {
      "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    }
  }
];

What I want is to include predefined rulesets, as I did in older iterations of Eslint with
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "google"],

But the only documentation I can find uses the module syntax and won't work with my script project is :
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
    js.configs.recommended,
    {
        rules: {
            "no-unused-vars": "warn"
        }
    }
];

How can I use eslint:recommended and Google in Eslint9 with commonjs syntax?

module.exports = [...]? Write a .mjs file?

But then I would have to change my package.json (my whole app) to module syntax, wouldn't I? That's not possible, as it is an browser run WebApp.

No, you only need to change it to type: module if you want to write ESM in .js files. Writing CJS in .js files and ESM in .mjs files are both fine in type: commonjs.

For whoever is looking for this:
As hinted by jonsharpe, mjs syntax will work. Als pure commonjs Syntax will work.
    const eslint = require("@eslint/js");
    const google = require("./eslint.google.config.js");
    const jsdoc = require('eslint-plugin-jsdoc');
    
    module.exports = [
      eslint.configs.recommended,
      google,
      {
        name: "HOKcheck",
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        ignores:  ["**/*.min.js"],
        languageOptions: {
          sourceType: "script", 
        },
        plugins: {
          jsdoc,
        },    
        rules: {
          'linebreak-style': ['error','windows'],
          'jsdoc/require-description': 'warn',
          "max-len": ["error", { "code": 160 }],
          "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "local", "args": "all" }]      
        }
      }
    ];

That said, currently the "eslint google config" project is not up to date for eslint9. You can fix it yourself easily, by commenting out the "valid-jsdoc" lines (arround line 66) in the js file pricoded by this plugin, and changing "'require-jsdoc': [2, {" (arround line 292) into "'jsdoc/require-jsdoc': [2, {" together with the config above.
